# anti glare protector for LG Gram 17

Tags: laptop

LG Gram 17 is very glossy.

https://www.notebookcheck.net/LG-Gram-13Z980-A-i5-8250U-Laptop-Review.295858.0.html

Is there any anti-glare protector?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon has one, the Flexzion Anti Glar Protector
[https://www.amazon.com/Flexzion-Anti-Glare-Protector-Widescreen-Displays/dp/B01B2P51BO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01B2P51BO)